# How to set a fixed windows size for a GTK+ app in C?

Tags: c, gtk

How do I set a fixed window size for a GTK+ app? I have:

```
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(mainWindow), 400, 300);
gtk_window_set_policy (GTK_WINDOW(mainWindow), FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);
```

but the window gets very small. There are no widgets yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `gtk_window_set_resizable` function for this purpose

```
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(mainWindow), 400, 300);
gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW(mainWindow), FALSE);
```

Comment: the problem is still there. The window remains small.
http://i.imgur.com/M9xkt.png  small with resizable false
http://i.imgur.com/51xPO.png  large with resizable true

Comment: Ah, you have no child widgets, that's why `gtk_window_set_resizable` resets size. Try `gtk_window_set_geometry_hints` to set minimum size of window

Comment: gtk_widget_set_size_request() would be a lot easier than set_geometry_hints

Answer (score 4):

```
gtk_widget_set_size_request(mainWindow, 400, 300);
gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW(mainWindow), FALSE);
```

This must solve the problem.