# gtk_window_set_resizable sets window to minimum

Tags: c, gcc, window, gtk

I have a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772804/how-to-set-a-fixed-windows-size-in-gtk-and-c). But it concern to answer.
I mean that call like

```
gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW(window), width, height);
gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
```

sets my window to tiniest one. Have you any idea?

Thanks.

Yury

Comment: possible duplicate of [GTK window resize disable without going back to default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193613/gtk-window-resize-disable-without-going-back-to-default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `gtk_window_set_geometry_hints` to set minimum size of window.