# gtk_window_set_default_size doesn't work

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have this code:

```
#define false FALSE
#define true TRUE
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[]){
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "window");

    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 230, 150);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), false);

    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), 0);

    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code with the line below and run it, the window ends up being 1x1px

```
gcc src/main.c -o test -Wall -O2 `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0`
```

If I remove the `gtk_window_set_resizable` line, it starts working again.

Why does this happen? Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Gtk, but does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974013/gtk-window-set-resizable-sets-window-to-minimum) answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So from reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974013/gtk-window-set-resizable-sets-window-to-minimum) question's answer, I learned that `gtk_window_set_default_size` doesn't work, so I replaced `gtk_window_set_default_size` with this instead:

```
GdkGeometry windowProperties;
windowProperties.min_width = 230;
windowProperties.min_height = 150;
gtk_window_set_geometry_hints(GTK_WINDOW(window), NULL, &windowProperties, GDK_HINT_MIN_SIZE);
```

Comment: Have you tried gtk_window_resize instead ? It may avoid messing up with GDK.

Comment: @liberforce I'll try sometime later. In the meantime, this works.