# Making GTK# Window non resizable

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have a GTK# Window i need to prevent user from resizing it.seen this answer [How to set a fixed windows size for a GTK+ app in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772804/how-to-set-a-fixed-windows-size-in-gtk-and-c) but i cannot find the correponding method for `gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW(mainWindow), FALSE);` for C# here http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.Window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_resizable()` is a setter function for `resizable` property. In languages where properties are a language feature (like C#)  these functions aren't needed.

In other words just use `mainWindow.Resizable = false`.